# typescript class constructor parameter inferred as any

Tags: typescript, constructor, type-inference

Let's analyse code snippet below:

```
class Human {
    private name: string;
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let h = new Human(5)
```

Above code ***doesn't*** throw any error. And I'd expect it to throw in the constructor call, where I pass `5`.

It seems that constructor's `name` parameter gets inferred as `any`, where, statically it's easy to find out that I'm assigning it to a `private name: string`.

**The question is: is there any particular reason that TypeScript is allowing `5` here - or in other words - that `name` is inferred as `any`, when in this case it's obvious that it has to be a string?**

I know I could do another class definition like this:

```
class Human {
    constructor(
        private name: string
    ){}
}
```

but here I specify the parameter type, so there's no inference here. The same way I could do:

```
class Human {
    private name: string;
    constructor(name: string){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and there would be no inference either. My question is about inference - why it works this way.

Comment: I think it's because typescript is compatible to and a subset of javascript. default type `any` made this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specific compiler option `noImplicitAny` specifically to address this. Without `"noImplicitAny": true`, your `name` is inferred as `any` so it does not complain when a `number` is passed.

> Why it works this way?

See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15196) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1265).

Comment: that's not the answer. I know about `noImplicitAny`. In above case, TS could have inferred the type - and it didn't...

Comment: the question is **WHY**

Comment: Ah, so you want Flow-like type inference on parameters. It's probably a design decision made by the team. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15196) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1265).

Comment: The links you gave me lead to very detailed answers on *why*. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

contructor( name ) declaration is equal to constructor( name: any ). Then, this.name = name assignment works seamlessly only because TS is backward-compatible with plain JS: when you assign the 'any' value to a strongly typed var, TS assumes you know what you're doing. So, conversion between number and string stays out of TS control and responsibility.

Comment: again, this is not an answer. I explicitly wrote that it infers the parameter as `any` - why are you repeating the same what I wrote? I'm asking why TS is not inferring, when logically it could.

Comment: from your answers, I feel, you don't even understand the question, sorry

Comment: being backawrds compatible to JS determines lack of overloading, for instance. But it has nothing to do with what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of ambiguity and computational complexity.

First of all, simple rules covering most of the cases are the best. This means the grammar of the language is simple, it's easy to learn it for newcomers and also easy to maintain the compiler itself.

Then, there could be corner cases where inferring a type of an argument by its usage would require a lot of traversing and thus a typo in the code could slow down the compilation.

Also, constructor is a type's external interface which is used by other parts of the application, so it should be explicit for clarity and safety. If your interface implicitly depends on the actual implementation, you can accidentally change something during refactoring and get hard-to-detect bugs.